javascript date increment by one day
I am trying to increment date by 1 day using javascript date object and print only the ymd format. The result date in the tomorrow variable after slicing is not 26 but 25 why so?


const d = new Date("2022-03-25");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;

var currentdate = new Date();
currentdate.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

var tomorrow = '';
tomorrow = currentdate.toJSON().slice(0, 10);

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = currentdate + ' , ' + tomorrow;
<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="demo1"></p>




Hint: remove the .slice(0,10) part and see what it prints

tojson converts to  iso date

@GuyIncognito - not working Sir.

I wasn't suggesting it as a solution to the problem. You asked "why so," so what is the timezone of currentdate.toJSON() compared to printing just currentdate?

you will need to minus the timezone offset from your currenttime and then convert to iso

if I run this snippet I see the expected result...

Why is this question tagged with jQuery? I don't see any jQuery code. What is d and how is it relevant for the question?

@LelioFaieta - sir, because as per your timezone, the time would have been changed from 11:59 to 00:00 hours, so day changed, so even after considering the timezone, the time at which you ran the script, the date automatically got corrected . The time is not visible in the code, which was creating confusion. Displaying the time we can identify the issue.

hmm why was this closed

The problem is after toJSON() you have got the time in UTC which is not your local time. So what you need is to format your time in the form of ISO String. But the problem is it converts your date to UTC first.
So the solution is to find the timezone offset and then minus it from your currentDate. This will now give a future/past date based on your local timezone. But in UTC it will convert to your local time.
So it is something like making your local location the UTC reference point


const d = new Date("2022-03-25");
const currentdate = new Date();
currentdate.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

console.log("current date in local timezone:", currentdate.toString())
console.log("current date in utc:", currentdate.toISOString())

const offset = currentdate.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log("timezone offset:",offset)

const currentDateConvertedToUtc = new Date(currentdate.getTime() - offset*60*1000)
console.log("current date converted to utc in local timezone:", currentDateConvertedToUtc.toString())
console.log("current date converted to utc in utc:", currentDateConvertedToUtc.toISOString())

const tomorrow= currentDateConvertedToUtc.toISOString().slice(0,10);
console.log(tomorrow)
//toJSON will give same as toISOString()



